# What are the chances of encountering a shiny Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

For Sun & Moon, are the chances to catch a shiny Pokémon the same of previous generations, like X & Y? Or are the chances somewhat higher or lower this time around?

Comment: The chances in X and Y were higher than in previous generations.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Oh were they?  Now I'm wondering if they made the rates even higher for this generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breeding with the Masuda Method, your chances of getting a shiny are 1 in 683. If you have the shiny charm *and* use the Masuda Method, your chances are 1 in 512. Thus, using the Masuda Method is the best.

With SOS chaining, if you get a chain of 70 and above, you have a 1 in 1024 chance, and with the shiny charm it becomes 1 in 683. Therefore, the Masuda Method still gives you a better chance, but the SOS chaining method may be faster if you turn off battle actions in your game options.

Comment: You should explain the Adrenaline Orb method, as it's written now is unclear and misleading. Also, any source of your numbers?

Comment: The Adrenaline Orb paragraph seems to be referring to the chance of getting a shiny while SOS chaining. Using an Adrenaline Orb does not increase the chance of finding a shiny at all, but it makes SOS chaining easier, and after getting up to a chain of 70+, the chances of encountering a shiny in the chain effectively become 1 in 1024.

Comment: As someone who isn't overly familiar with shiny Pokémon or methods to catch them, this answer is a really bad resource.  The question was about _encountering_ shines, and you talk about breeding through the "medusa method" without explaining what it is or providing a resource.  You then mention SOS chaining, which again, no way to tell what that is from your answer.  I own the game and this answer has me no closer to knowing the odds of a shiny encounter because it's not clear what these methods are.

Answer (score 6):

Reportedly, they are the same as they were in gen6: **1 in 4096**

The [Masuda Method](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Masuda_method) (breeding two Pokémon from different languages) still works to increase your chances of breeding a shiny. The way(s) of increasing the chances of wild shiny Pokémon have been replaced with [Ally Chaining](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/pokemon-sun-and-moon-how-get-shiny-pokemon-using-ally-chaining-and-masuda-method-569279), which involves using an Adrenaline Orb to force the wild Pokémon to call an ally for help, KO one of the two, and let the remaining one call for help, until you encounter a shiny.

Comment: This is somewhat confirmed by an NPC in the first town on Akala Island, who will say (paraphrasing) "Your chances of finding a shiny Pokemon are about 1 in 4000". Not sure if this changes when you get the shiny charm.